# How to check if extension has been activated in each tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created a Chrome extension. The function works fine in a single page.
Currently the problem is that how to check if the extension has been activated in each tab. So I can re-initialise the toolbar icon.

Steps to reproduce:
1. In page A, active the extension, change toolbar icon to close icon.
2. Open a new page B, the icon still keep using close icon.

I just want to make the toolbar icon reflect to each page.

I try to use tabs onUpdated, but it will affect the extension activated page.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
        path: "images/logo.png"
    });
});
```

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), there's `tabId` parameter you can specify in setIcon.

Answer (score 0):

You could call [chrome.browserAction.setIcon()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon) passing **tabId** key, like:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
        tabId: my-tab-id,
        path: {"images/logo.png"}
      });
```

You could also update the icon from background to all tabs, when some condition happens, so you could do something like this:

```
if (someCondition) {

  chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {    
    tabs.forEach(tab => {    
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
        tabId: tab.id,
        path: {"images/logo-A.png"}//ICON A
      });
    });    
  });


} else {

  chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {

    tabs.forEach(tab => {    
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
        tabId: tab.id,
        path: {"images/logo-B.png"}//ICON B
      });
    });    
  });

}
```